# Is there a word like father-tongue?

Tags: terminology, native-language

If  a  Telugu  speaking   woman  married   an  English man   and  the children  speak  the  two  languages  equally well and  that  is possible in the  global  context.

What  will be the  mother-tongue  of  the  children.?

Is there a  word  like  father-tongue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A distinction is sometimes made by some speakers (who are not usually fluent English speakers), who treat "mother tongue" compositionally rather than as a technical term meaning (well, that in itself is a problem) "native language" or "first language", often labeled "mother tongue". For example, "My mother tongue is Pare and my father tongue is Gogo". Linguists usually approach the problem more conversationally by asking a person about the languages that they speak, and which ones they use for what purpose. In that context, if you were to have started by asking "What is your mother tongue?", you could get an answer to the question "which of your two 'dominant' languages does your mother speak?", and you might need to probe deeper to find out about their "father tongue".

Native English speaking linguists generally do not talk of languages being "tongues", so as a technical term, "father tongue" is unusual. You may encounter it in non-technical contexts as in the Gogo / Pare example, or as a somewhat quirky term for a [language revitalization](https://blogs.ntu.edu.sg/wkwsci-fyp-collection/2016/05/23/%EF%BB%BFmy-father-tongue-a-campaign-to-revitalise-the-use-of-chinese-dialects-among-youth-in-singapore/) effort (read about the project name [here](https://fionaseah.com/tag/my-father-tongue/)). There is, though, a journal called [Mother Tongue](http://www.aslip.org/mt.html), which is about language prehistory, and this inspired the construction [Father Tongue hypothesis](https://s3.amazonaws.com/academia.edu.documents/36272178/ShompenMTXIII.pdf?response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3DThe_Shompen_of_Great_Nicobar_Island_New.pdf&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWOWYYGZ2Y53UL3A%2F20190926%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20190926T174611Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=822fe6e1e84321b15f6b489e4d30225d7a49e19d53409326cc762dffab47d720), which has nothing to do with what languages you or your parents speak.

I don't know if speakers of Indian English would find it unusual for a person to say "My mother tongue is Telugu and my father tongue is English".

Answer (score 5):

The *idea* of mother tongue can [break down](https://expatsincebirth.com/2019/02/19/mothertongue-first-language-native-language-or-dominant-language/) when you have more than one language learned by the child. Multilingual families are often the ones who see this the most.

There are various labels for all the different functions of each language, e.g. "dominant language", ["first language"](https://www.daytranslations.com/blog/how-many-mother-tongue/), but I think "mother tongue" and "native language" are the only ones that are [common enough](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mother%20tongue%2Cnative%20language%2Cfather%20tongue%2Cdominant%20language&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=4&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cmother%20tongue%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmother%20tongue%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMother%20Tongue%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMother%20tongue%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cnative%20language%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bnative%20language%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNative%20Language%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNative%20language%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cfather%20tongue%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bfather%20tongue%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BFather%20tongue%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BFather%20Tongue%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cdominant%20language%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdominant%20language%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BDominant%20language%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BDominant%20Language%3B%2Cc0) to be recognised by most English-speaking people.

[One specific use of the term "father tongue"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Father_Tongue_hypothesis) was coined to explain how the Y-chromosome (only passed from fathers to sons) links to language acquisition, and [one proposed reconciliation](https://phys.org/news/2018-08-mother-tongue-father-tonguea.html) of mother tongue vs father tongue is the [hypothesis](https://www.thewordling.com/blog/fathertonguehypothesis) that children learn [phonemes from the mother but lexicon from the father](https://academic.oup.com/nsr/advance-article/doi/10.1093/nsr/nwy083/5076917).